# How can I remove unmounted SD Card icons from my desktop?

Tags: mount, unmount

I have been using some audio utilities in Ubuntu 11.10 to tweak .mp3 files on my phone (Motorola Photon 4G). I connect via USB... both my phone and the internal SD card are mounted as two separate drives. The SD card has an unusual drive name with some odd characters.

When I'm finished, I unmount my phone (or "safely remove drive"), but the SD card can't be unmounted.  I've mounted and unmounted my phone on 4 occasions now, and there are now 4 SD card drive icons that I can't remove from the desktop.  I tried using the gconf-editor/apps/nautilus/desktop trick to make drives invisible and it's not working. Right-clicking on the icons and selecting "unmount" produced the following error message;

(I can't type the unusual drive name characters... replaced with xxx)

```
Unable to unmount xxx
umount: /media/xxx is not mounted (according to mtab)
```

How can I remove the unwanted icons from the desktop and is there a method for avoiding this problem in the future?  Thanks!

Comment: Try `unity --reset`

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**

Install Ubuntu Tweak

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Under `Desktop > Desktop Icon Setting`, choose to hide or show desktop icons.

**Method 2**

Install gconf

```
sudo apt-get install
```

Run it by pressing `Alt+F2` and type this `gconf-editor`

In the Configuration editor, go to `apps > nautilus > desktop`. Untick the box that corresponds to the icons you'd like to hide.

To hide all desktop icons, go to `apps > nautilus > preferences`, look for `show_desktop` and untick the box.